# How do I delete colons (:) in my lists?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am starting to learn racket. There is a example which is about time and I need remove colons (:) from my list. For example;

11:30 -> 1130

I want to do it because I will putting them in order which is first, second, third and fourth.

P.S.: Sorry about my English.

Comment: @samoth 

First, I write it

(define (check L)
  (for ([i (in-range 0 (length L))])
    (remove : L)
  )
  (display L)
)

(check (list 22:30 22:31 ))

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between output and input. **1)** your question asks to remove colons yet they appear in your output **2)** there seems to be no correlation between inputs and outputs. why are some times left out of the output completely? **3)** `"14:30"` shows up in the output but it is not an input.

Comment: @naomik yes, you're right. it is irrelance, i corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define L (list "22:30"))

(string-append (substring (first L) 0 2) (substring (first L) 3 5))
```

Output: "2230"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(string-replace "11:30" ":" "")
```

If you need to do something with the digits, you can convert your string into a number or a list of digits. It goes like this:

```
;; convert a string into an integer 
(define S (string->number (string-replace "11:30" ":" "")))

;; produce a list of digits from a given integer
(define (int->list n) 
  (cond [(zero? n) empty]
        [else
         (append (int->list (quotient n 10))
             (list (remainder n 10)))]))

;; try it in REPL
> (int->list S)
'(1 1 3 0)
```

Comment: Try using `cons` rather than `append`; you can always `reverse` the result if necessary. It's an incredible performance booster and makes your code look way more professional ;-)

Comment: Sure, I do use it in my code, as well as tail recursion, when performance is important. But in this example code with only four-element list you probably won't notice any difference in performance even with profiling tools, will you? With performance in focus, I'd probably rewrite the whole thing using string->list from the standard library, depending on what OP needs. The latter is exactly the problem, as it's not clear what OP's attempting to do with this string of digits.